# Problems with version 1.4.1.1 in round up special price

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.4.1.1 and tried use the clue of friend (Daniel Sloof)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411971/round-special-price-only-in-magento] after no worked. Before restore bkp.

I am using grouped product and the need to apply rounding for up in discounted price for all group customers, wholesale:30%, wholesale:40%, wholesale:50%

I try use in: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

```
public function roundPrice($price)  
{
return round((ceil($price*10)/10), 2);
}
```

The problem is in the shopping cart, this rounding the SUBTOTAL and it can not.
or an easier way (correct) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The roundPrice method is used for most places where the price is shown to the user, so this would definitely change other prices shown on the site too.

You could try and override the getSpecialPrice method in the product model. This can be done by copying app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php and modifying it there.

```
/**
 * Returns special price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getSpecialPrice()
{
    return $this->_getData('special_price');
}
```

change to:

```
/**
 * Returns special price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getSpecialPrice()
{
    return round((ceil($this->_getData('special_price')*10)/10), 2);
}
```

**I've not tested this**, it could well cause issues I am not sure without looking further, there could be places where Magento gets the special price another way without using this method so you would have to test that for yourself :)

Comment: this change did not affect the catalog and also not affect Cart
`return round((ceil($this->_getData('special_price')*10)/10), 2);`